# Approve github PR in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, github

I am trying to create a process that blocks a github PR from being approved and merged to the main branch until a Jenkins pipeline can confirm that a terraform plan (or whatever checks need to happen for that repo) are successful.

There are two restrictions with though

1. we're not allowed to install plugins that aren't approved by the company, and that's just too much hassle!
2. the Jenkins instance is internal so I can't use a webhook

I'm trying to use a multibranch pipeline to execute when a PR is raised but I can't see how to approve the PR once the check is complete, perhaps this isn't the best way to go?

I'd appreciate any help/pointers on this

Thanks

Comment: If your Company Firewall allows you to call Github API you can make use of [statuses](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#statuses) api

Comment: Hi @SamitKumarPatel I'm not sure how I can block/unblock the permission to commit to master.  I'm thinking of using branch protection but I can't see an API call that I can use for that

Comment: branch protection can be enabled or disable via API but it was limited to some version of GitHub. please take a look on [github api](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#update-branch-protection)